# can I call nodejs apps from php?

Tags: php, node.js

I am trying to do...

```
<?php $content = `echo 'h1 happy days' | jade`; ?>
```

But it does not return anything. Other commands do (for example `ls`)

I tried adding jade to the path, making a link in `/bin` which works from the command line, but not from within php.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

From command line:

```
bash-3.2$ pwd
/Users/billy/test/website-clear
bash-3.2$ echo 'h1 happy days' | jade
<h1>happy days</h1>bash-3.2$ which jade
/bin/jade
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: And this works 100% correctly from the command line?

Comment: @Matchu - yes it does, see edit

Comment: @Esailija just tried now - same result, no error - no content

Comment: Just to verify: you are trying to store the result of calling `'h1 happy days' | jade` to a PHP variable?

Comment: Yes I am... and I now know why it is not working...

Comment: Turns out, I did not have node in my path - a symlink to node in the /bin directory did the trick - happy days'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two other options that might suit you well:
1. proc_open if you want more degree of control:

```
    $handle = proc_open("jade", array( array("pipe", "r"), array("pipe", "w"), array("pipe", "w")), $pipes);
    fwrite($pipes[0], 'h1 happy days');
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    $result = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    return $result;
```

2. Using exec:

```
    exec("echo 'h1 happy days' | jade", $output, $retval);
    return $output;
```

Make sure that you have jade in path or use the full path to jade executable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) function. I believe your external call creates it's own context by the operating system, which then gets it's own stdin/stdout/stderr. Do this instead:

```
<?php $content = system("echo 'h1 happy days' | jade", $retval); ?>
```